# Multiple pcap files to csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file, pcap

i have a folder that contain a thousands of pcap files, and i want to convert each pcap file into a csv file

Example:

```
convert 1.pcap to 1.csv
convert 2.pcap to 2.csv
convert 3.pcap to 3.csv
```

.bat file:

```
@echo off 
set "cap_files=*.cap"
set "cap_folder="D:\testfolder\"
Cd /d "%cap_folder%"
set "tshark_cmd="c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark"
set "tshark_options=-n -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f "

for /d %cap_folder% %%f in (%cap_files%) do(
    echo Processing File: %%f %tshark_cmd%  -r %%f %tshark_options% >>%%~nf.csv)
```

There is no output and output is :
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XfiR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am unfortunately not able to test as I do not have your executables, but if you want to convert each `.cap` file to it's own `.csv`, then something like this should probably do:

```
@echo off 
set "cap_folder=D:\testfolder\"
Cd /d "%cap_folder%"
set "tshark_cmd=c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark"
set "tshark_options=-n -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "*.cap"') do (
   echo Processing File: %%i
   "%tshark_cmd%" -r %%i %tshark_options% >>%cap_folder%\%%~ni.csv
)
```

Comment: Is there any thing else to do ? should i try a shell script !! it might work ? or what exactly ?! any recommandation sir .. (By the way, thanks for everything, thank u so much).